# Is there a way to draw 3D-style "buttons"?

Tags: diagrams

I was wondering if there is a latex package to get pseudo-3D style "buttons" as are often seen on the web, or if not is there an easy way to draw them?

An example of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: You mean those 80x15px things? Maybe you could explain what use you have in mind?

Comment: What do you mean by WYSIWYM an by “web buttons” in this context? Like Carsten, I have problems understanding the question.

Comment: I'd like to get something like that by using latex code and not a program like Inkscape... I can get similar buttons with the tikz picture but not with this shiny color effects..

Comment: Do you just want the shape, or do you want the interactivity as well?  (That is, does a clicked-on button need to do anything?)

Comment: shape, color shining and shadowing effects

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer what was asked (since this question recently came up again).  That makes it easier for people searching for something similar to find it.  Feel free to re-edit it if you don't like what I did.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is an example of a simple button created with tikz:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   button/.style={
   rectangle,
   minimum size=6mm,
   very thick,
   rounded corners,
   draw=red!50!black!74,
   top color=red!50!black!70,
   bottom color=white,
   }]
   \node[button] (button) {A Button!};
   \begin{scope}[opacity=.6, transparency group]
      \draw[white,fill=white,rounded corners={2pt}] ($ (button.north west) + (3pt,-3pt) $) rectangle ($ (button.north east) + (-3pt,-8pt) $);
      \draw[white,fill=white,rounded corners={.5pt}] ($ (button.north west) + (3pt,-5pt) $) rectangle ($ (button.north east) + (-3pt,-8pt) $);
   \end{scope}
   \draw[white,fill=white,opacity=.8,rounded corners={1pt}] ($ (button.south west) + (5pt,2pt) $) rectangle ($ (button.south east) + (-5pt,4pt) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I then used pdfcrop to crop the file, and gimp to convert the pdf to png:

[image: button]

Basically you do the same you would do in Inkscape, except that you don't have very good support for things like fading etc, so it will be somewhat limited.

Comment: Thanks!This is exactly what I meant ;-) (I'll do some research on pdfcrop because I've never heard of it). Thanks again!

Comment: @Arianna. This answer seems to solve your issue: please consider accepting it by choosing the 'tick' underneath the voting arrows.

Answer (score 26):

Here's a little playground for this inspirational question and answers (plain-tex format; adjust for latex etc.):

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols,shadows}
\tikzpicture[
  button/.style={text=white,draw=#1!50!black,
    preaction={drop shadow={shadow scale=1.05,shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    top color=#1!10,bottom color=#1!50!black,inner xsep=2ex,inner ysep=1.6ex,
  },
  plastic/.style={button=#1,shape=rectangle,rounded corners=1.6ex},
  oval/.style={button=#1,shape=rectangle,rounded corners=2.5ex,ball color=#1},
  any size/.style={button=#1,shape=ellipse,inner xsep=1ex, inner ysep=1ex},
  slick/.style={button=#1,shape=tape,tape bend height=1ex,inner sep=1ex},
  candy wrap/.style={button=#1,shape=rectangle,rounded corners=5ex},
  smooth/.style={button=#1,shape=rectangle,rounded corners=2ex,
    top color=#1!50!black,shading angle=45,bottom color=#1!10}
]
\draw (0,0)
\foreach \color in {red,green,blue} {
  \foreach \shape in {plastic,oval,any size,slick,candy wrap,smooth} {
    node[\shape=\color] {\shape} ++(2.5,0)
  }
  ++(-15,1)
};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

[image]