# Shiny button-like node style with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web buttons with WYSIWYM](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7566/web-buttons-with-wysiwym)

Would it be possible with TikZ to draw (3D) shiny button-like nodes as those appearing in the mindmap on page 44 of Lukas Doktor presentation "Diagram, graph, and mindmap software" showed at http://rvokal.fedorapeople.org/devconf/ldoktor-grafy.pdf ? It Seems that this implies defining a node as two imbeded round rectangles, and a third half one (simulating reflexion) ... Many thanks for any hint. Jean-Marc

Comment: Very good question.  This seems like a job for tikz fadings.

Comment: Marc: do you want the exact same thing as in the link you provided?  Or are the answers in the suggested duplicate sufficient?

Comment: It is quite sufficient. Many thanks for the answers. The thread "Web buttons with WYSIWYM" gives good solutions to my problem, and many cues to obtain node styles alike what I needed. Jean-Marc

Comment: I've just tried to clean up the "Web buttons with WYSIWYM" question to make it clearer what's being asked there.  If I were looking for this then I wouldn't have known that that question had the answer!